# MySQL query to get data between and not between where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

This MySQL query is to get data from two tables `exam_dates` and `section_strength` and join them to get total persons from which sections has completed there exam in march quarter:

```
select s.section, count(section), r.strength 
from exam_dates s 
  left join section_strength r 
    on s.section=r.section_name 
where s.semester_exam between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-31' 
group by s.section
```

But this query is showing only those sections name who have completed the exam in march quarter. I want all the name of sections in left side and number of persons completed next column and then the strength of that section.

first table contains=> details of student completed exam on "so and so dates"
example:

### id| personal_no| section_name| semester_dates

### 1 |  777878     | hrm         |2017-01-12

### 2 | 748587       |it             |2017-05-10

another table having strength of individual sections:

### id|section_name |strength

### 1 | hrm          | 10

### 2 | it          | 15

Now I want my query to show result of all sections name in left side and then total student completed test in march quarter and then total strength of that section.
for eg.

### id|section_name|total_completed|strength

### 1 | hrm        |  2            |  10

### 2 | it         |  5            |  15

Comment: NO NEED TO YELL. Just explain yourself calmly and tag the question accordingly. You've already said "mysql" several times.

Comment: You have two non-aggregate columns in your `SELECT` clause and only one in your `GROUP BY`. I understand MySQL allows you to be lazy about this but it doesn't help in understanding the problem. Can you show an example of the data and how you'd like it to appear in this query result?

Comment: Also, what data type is `exam_dates.semester_exam`?

Comment: Maybe replace your where with and

Comment: Replacing with " and"  helps. Also I have to left join with the section_strength table first.

Answer (score -1):

Your second date is before your first date. Try reversing the order of the dates:

```sql
select s.section, count(section), r.strength
from exam_dates s
left join section_strength r on s.section=r.section_name
where s.semester_exam between '2017-03-31' and '2017-01-01'
group by s.section
```

Comment: *"Your second date is before your first date"* <- how do you figure that?